# Exporting Jenkin's Checkstyle graphical report to HTML

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle

Is it possible to export the Checkstyle/PMD etc reports/graphs which are generated by jenkins checkstyle plugin? Basically I want that checkstyle report to be archived to zip file and store it in our backup location. Is this possible? If not possible, where does Jenkins store the checkstyle graphs reports? Can anyone guide me? I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the Send build artifacts over SSH (if your backup location is Unix).  Look at the documentation for the plugin here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

As far as where Jenkins stores the report files that depends on where you configured your build script to send them.  Ant has the toFile attribute.  If you use Maven it uses the outputDirectory parameter.